# Hamming distance between two large ndarrays (optimization of large array multiplication)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to write a letter recognition program in Python that would categorize handwritten letters into categories basing on their similarities to letters from a training set. I've chosen to represent the difference between the pictures by the hamming distance between the matrix containing the binary representations of pictures from the test dataset (one row = one picture) and the matrix of pictures from the train dataset.
I've optimized the function so it's not three loops, instead it utilizes the more efficient matrix multiplication. But sadly it's still too inefficient to be fast enough at processing the entire training set that is available to me (more than 25000 pictures). 
I'm looking for suggestions on how I could possibly improve performance. I know sparse matrices are a thing, but would it actually be more efficient to try and multiply them?
I've also been unsuccessful in trying to find an answer if there is a performance difference in performing operation on slices of very large arrays and equivalent copies of the slices (with slices being views into the arrays and all).

This is my hamming distance function:

```
def hamming_distance(X, X_train):
  X_train = np.transpose(X_train)
  NOT_X = np.subtract(np.ones(shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[1])), X)
  NOT_X_train = np.subtract(np.ones(shape=(X_train.shape[0], 
  X_train.shape[1])), X_train)
  return X @ NOT_X_train + NOT_X @ X_train
```

PS. I'm still very new to Python. Thanks to everyone who took their time to read this question.

Comment: so this is different hamming distance than https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.hamming.html#scipy.spatial.distance.hamming?